# Ruby On Rails - Self-Referential association: Avoid creating twice the same Friendship Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model:

```
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user
```

And a `Friendship` model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

`Friendship` table has both `user_id` and `friend_id`(`user_id` is the `id` of the `user` that creates the `friendship` relationship).

I want to add a `validation` that disallows creating twice the same `friendship` relationship (look at the example below):

```
## first_user has id = 103
## second_user has id = 209
## I don't want to have:
Frienship<id = 1072, user_id = 103, friend_id = 209>
Frienship<id = 3022, user_id = 209, friend_id = 103>
## i.e, I don't want to store this relationship two times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations):

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :friendship_validation

  private

  def friendship_validation
    if Friendship.where("(user_id=? AND friend_id=?) OR (user_id=? AND friend_id=?)", self.user_id, self.friend_id, self.friend_id, self.user_id).any?
      errors.add(:friendship, "friendship exists")
    end
  end
end
```